# Why I am able to access the users of a different tenant without adding any API permission to application in Azure Portal?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-msal, microsoft-identity-platform

I created an application named `MyApp` in my `Tenant A` with multitenant access. Also, I didn't add any API permissions to it in Azure Portal. I also removed default `User.Read` permission.
[image]

After that, I implement a backend project with using `msal4j` library. In backend code, I sent harcoded scope `Directory.ReadWrite.All`.

After that, I run the backend project. The project showed Microsoft sign in pop up in the browser.  I provided the credentials of admin of another tenant named `B`(`Tenant B` have 16 users). After the successful sign in, the Permission Requested pop-up showed, It was written a description about the `Directory.ReadWrite.All`. This was normal since I was add `Directory.ReadWrite.All` as a scope in my backend code.

After approving that requested permission as an admin of `Tenant B`. I can list the 16 users of the `Tenant B` with `GET /users` endpoint of the `Microsoft Graph API`. So, the `MyApp` which was created in `Tenant A` could access the users of `Tenant B`.

However, how it was possible? Because I didn't add any API permission to my `MyApp` in the Azure Portal. You can see above screnshot that is empty. I expected to get an error like `"Insufficient privilege"` when accessing the `GET /users` endpoint. But I didn't. I can successfully access the all 16 users although I didn't add the `Directory.ReadWrite.All` API permission in the Azure Portal into `MyApp`.

If sending `Directory.ReadWrite.All` as scope from backend project is enough to access to `GET /users` endpoint. Why we want to use `API permissions` in the Azure Portal?

Comment: Have you tried to get the access token which you used to call the API? I think you can get the access token first and then use jwt and decrypt it, then you can know which application you are using and which authention flow you are using. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Azure portal permissions are what we call static permissions.
You use them with the ".default" special scope, e.g. `https://graph.microsoft.com/.default`.

When you specify a scope in the authentication request, that is a dynamic permission.
It is a feature of the newer v2 endpoint that allows you to request the needed permissions at runtime instead of ahead of time.
It's pretty nice for multi-tenant apps since updating permissions can be done more easily, and you can implement optional features better (that require additional permissions).

Docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-permissions-and-consent and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/consent-framework